# how to make a select query to run more than 30 mins on simple table with 4 columns (sno,sname,job,dept) having 10 records?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, database-connection, database-deadlocks

I wanted to make a test case with my application server which connects to the oracle database and executes select query . This select query need to be run more than 30 mins and has to return the result from the table having 4 columns (sno,sname,job,dept). Could you please give me a select query which runs more than 30 mins ?

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE FUNCTION sleep (
  seconds IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP( seconds );
  -- In 18c+, use DBMS_SESSION instead, since that package requires less privileges.
  -- DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP( seconds );
  RETURN seconds;
END;
/
```

Then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       ( SELECT sleep( 30*60 + 1 ) FROM DUAL ) s;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, Could you assist me on the following table , how can i use the above queries.

Comment: mysql> select * from employee;
+------+-------+---------+---------+
| sno  | sname | job     | dept    |
+------+-------+---------+---------+
|  100 | John  | admin   | mid     |
|  101 | Bob   | quality | ptm     |
|  102 | Cath  | trans   | release |
|  103 | Bret  | dev     | build   |
|  104 | Steve | capt    | team    |
+------+-------+---------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Run it in Oracle (since the question is tagged Oracle) - if you want a MySQL answer then it should work without creating the function as MySQL has a native [`SLEEP()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep).

Comment: Thank you .. this query worked for me 

SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       ( SELECT sleep( 30*60 + 1 ) FROM DUAL ) s;